# Saving a file share link in a SharePoint list column

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

I have to save a fileshare link in a sharepoint list and i want that file to be opened when the link is clicked, the normal sharepoint hyperlink column does not work for me in this case as it embeds the http:// with the url. How can I handle this scenario? the link i want to save is in the format \192.168.1.2\myserver\myfile.pdf and the text to be shown in the column is "myfile"

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget a backslash?

`\\192.168.1.2\myserver\myfile.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

The first question would be why are you storing files in shared folders (e.g. \SERVER\SHARE\FILES etc) rather than inside a SharePoint document library?

If you can move the files to a doc library then this problem goes away (plus you get all the other doc library goodies such as versioning)

Assuming you want/have to keep with UNC paths you have the choice of using the file:// protocol so

if you put in

```
\\192.168.1.2\myserver\myfile.pdf
```

This will be converted to

```
file://192.168.1.2/myserver/myfile.pdf
```

(or of course you can enter it using file:// in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

You can save a `.url` file in a regular document library, but this file extension is blocked by default in SCA.

If you have access to Sharepoint Central Administration, you can easily unblock the `.url` extension by just deleting it from the list.  [Check out this technet article with directions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointcomic/archive/2009/01/07/blocked-file-types-in-sharepoint.aspx).

You can also unblock `.lnk` files in the same fashion, for they, too, are blocked by default.

With that said, you can create a shortcut on your desktop to the file, complete with the network file location via UNC path, and just upload the .lnk file.